How to define and train a function $f(x,y)$ with a boundary condition?
I have a dataset consisting of triplets $(x_i,y_i,z_i), i=1,2,\cdots,N$, where $x_i,y_i,z_i\in \mathbb{R}$. My goal is to find a function $f(x,y)$ that satisfies the following conditions:

Boundary condition: $f(x, 0)=x, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}$
Target approximation: $f(x_i, y_i)\approx z_i, i=1,2,\cdots,N$

This can be expressed as a constrained optimization problem:
$$\min_f\sum_{i=1}^{N}\ell(f(x_i,y_i),z_i)\\\text{s.t. }f(x,0)=x$$
where $\ell(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a loss function.
My Approach: Let $f(x,y)=x+yg(x,y)$, and then train function $g$.
Questions:

Is this approach to enforce the boundary condition appropriate and robust?
Are there alternative ways to model $f(x,y)$ that might simplify or improve this formulation?
From a statistical perspective, how should I interpret this problem? For example, would modeling $p(z|x,y)$ explicitly as a probabilistic model (e.g., Gaussian) provide additional benefits?

Thank you for your insights and suggestions!

Do the points $(x_i, y_i)$ form a grid? This could simplify a lot of things.

Yes, $(x_i, y_i)$ form a grid.
